# Complement set of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am a little confused clould someone clarify for me.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ continuous i want to show that $A=\left \{ (x,f(x)):x\epsilon \mathbb{R} \right \}$ is a close set of  $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ with the euclidean norm.

i tried to took the complement of $A$ with same restrictions and show that for every restriction the complement is open.i give an example.

lets say $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow (0,+\infty ) $ what is the complemet of $A$ ? $\mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus A= (\: \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R})\setminus \mathbb{R}\times [0,+\infty )$ which i am not sure what it is.

Could someone clarify this for me , thank you.

Comment: The complement of $A$ would be $\{(x,y):x\in \mathbb R, y\ne f(x)\}$.  You can prove that is open but it'd be easier to use the converging sequence/limit point definition of closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show $A$ is closed, start with a sequence $\{(x_n,f(x_n))\}$ in $A$ converging to $(x,y)$. And try to show $y=f(x)$ using continuity of $f$.
$(x_n,f(x_n))\rightarrow (x,y)$ gives $x_n\rightarrow x$ and $f(x_n)\rightarrow y$. Now continuity of $f$ gives $x_n\rightarrow  x \implies f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x)$. Now, since a sequence have at most one limit, so $y=f(x)$. Thus, $(x,y)\in A$. Hence $A$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :** You can write

$$A=g^{-1}(\lbrace 0 \rbrace)$$

where $g : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ by
$$g(x,y)=y-f(x)$$

Comment: why you took $y-f(x)$ as $g$ could it work and for  $y+f(x)$, and what about the complemet how is it defined mathematicaly?

Comment: No, it would not work with $y+f(x)$. Think about what is $g^{-1}(0)$ for the function $g$ defined in the answer.

Comment: as $f(x)$ approx $y$ then the distance between $f(x)-y$ goes to $0$ so thats why

Comment: There is no approximation or limit here. I defined a function $g$, such that $A$ can be written as $g^{-1}(0)$. That's all.

Comment: so since ${0}$ is closed that means $A$ is closed?

Comment: Yes, because $g$ is continuous.